# AMD Socket FM1 A8 3870 3.0Ghz ASUS F1A75-M LE

Tags: installation, bios, computer-building, integrated-graphics

I am building a new computer for my wife and plan on using an:

- AMD socket FM1 A8 3870 3.0Ghz quad core processor
- ASUS f1a75-M LE motherboard
- Corsair xms3 8gb 1600 memory (2x4)
- Western Digital Caviar Blue 750gb hd
- OCZ Vertex 120 gb SSD
- Coolmax blue 700 watt psu
- Pioneer 24x dvdrw
- HEC Blitz mid tower case
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

Are there any recommended settings that I need to pay close attention too in the BIOS? For example, both the CPU and motherboard have integrated graphics (AMD Radeon HD 6550D and HD 6000, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Prior to installing Windows, be sure to enable ACHI for your SATA controller. It will allow Windows to use [Native Command Queuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) which has a significant performance increase over IDE mode.

Answer (score -1):

Heating is a problem, don't go with the stock fan.

Comment: I was wondering about a different cooling fan. I will look for one. Thanks.